# In Node.JS, how to parse JSON object to Model class?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, nosql, jsonparser

In a Node-Express-Mongo app, I am using Mongodb native driver to connect DB. 
My Question is,

> how to convert the incoming request object to corresponding Model
>   class.

I know, using Mongoose we can create schema from there and I want to build model using that schema. But I am not using mongoose driver, I need a solution for using native / mongojs driver.

Comment: Don't get it.  The mongojs driver works with plain old javascript objects. You should be able to work directly with the json that comes in on request.body.

Comment: @bhuvanesh adding a code snippet of what you have tried, would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add your current model and what you want to do?